# Jordan normal Form and Transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I am solving an example to find the Jordan form and the transformation matrix of the following $4 \times 4$ matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}a&0&1&0\\ 1&a&1&1\\ 0&0&a&0\\ 0&0&1&a\end{pmatrix}
I went through the solution manually as follows:

(1). Eigenvalue $(a- \lambda)^4$, so $\lambda=a$ with an algebraic multiplicity of $4$.

(2). Geometric multiplicities

$$\ker(A-\lambda I) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&1\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$

so $\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)) = 2$ and

$$\ker(A- \lambda I) = \text{span}\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\}$$

$$ \ker(a-\lambda I)^2 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&2&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$

so $\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)^2) = 3$ and $$\ker(A-\lambda I)^2 = \text{span}\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\}$$

$$ \ker(a-\lambda I)^3 = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} $$

so $\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)^3) = 4$ and $$\ker(A-\lambda I)^3 = \text{span}\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\}$$

(3). Transformation matrix
$w_3 \in \ker(A-\lambda I)^3$, and $w_3 \not\in \ker(A-\lambda I)^2$

So let we say,

$w_{k-1}=(A-\lambda I) \cdot w_k$

so I can get:

$$ w3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}, w2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}, w2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} and u1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So the Jordan form is
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&1&0&0\\ 0&a&1&0\\ 0&0&a&0\\ 0&0&0&a\end{pmatrix}$$

the Trans. matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

I am not sure of my hand solution, but using the Matlab function, gives

V =

```
                         [0    1    -2    -1]
                         [                  ]
                         [2    0     0     0]
                         [                  ]
                         [0    0     1     0]
                         [                  ]
                         [0    1     1     1]
```

J =

```
                          [a    1    0    0]
                          [                ]
                          [0    a    1    0]
                          [                ]
                          [0    0    a    0]
                          [                ]
                          [0    0    0    a]
```

I want to know what is the wrong step in my hand solution to get the same result!
Thank you!

Comment: The above transformation matrix (base change matrix) in your version has a zero row and/or column, it is singular...

Comment: So, is it wrongly solved in one step

Comment: For an answer it is a long typing trip. As a short comment here, it would be nice to have a better (compact and clear) format for the question, as it is, i can not even extract the notations for the many vectors used. We know that all eigenvalues are $a$, so let us subtract $a$ times the the identity from the given matrix. The remained matrix, $N$ say, is easy to inspect. Which is its kernel explicitly? Which is the kernel of $N$, $N^2$, $N^3$, $N^4$?

Comment: The element $w_4$ of $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda I)^3$ that is not in $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda I)^2$ will give you three vectors: $w_4$, $w_3=(A-\lambda I)w_4$, and $w_2=(A-\lambda I)w_3 = (A-\lambda I)^2w_4$. The  last one lies in the eigenspace, which has dimension $2$, so you need to find a fourth vector $w_1$, which lies in $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda I)$ and is linearly independent from $w_2$.  The $w_3$ that you picked lies in $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda I)^2$, which is why you got that zero vector that you shouldn't have.

Comment: As to Matlab, remember that while the Jordan form is unique (up to order of blocks), the transformation matrix very  much is not. So don't be surprised if MathLab gives you something different.

Comment: Ok, I will check with your suggestion. Thank you